# How to insert value to an array based on if statement in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to add value to an array in python.

```
def inputUser():

    name.append(raw_input("Enter name = "))
    age.append(raw_input("Enter age = "))
    typeService.append(raw_input("Enter code of service type = "))
    action=raw_input("Do you want to add another kitten = ")

    while action != "n":    
        name.append(raw_input("Enter name = "))
        age.append(raw_input("Enter age = "))
        typeService.append(raw_input("Enter code of service type = "))
        action=raw_input("Do you want to add another kitten = ")

def calcFee():
    for i in range(len(name)):
        if age[i] <= 5:
            if typeService[i] == 1:
                price.append(15)
            elif typeService[i] == 2:
                price.append(50)
        elif age[i] > 5:
            if typeService[i] == 1:
                price.append(20)
            elif typeService[i] == 2:
                price.append(60)

def display():

    for i in range(len(name)):
        print(name[i])
        print(age[i])
        print(typeService[i])
        print(price[i])

inputUser()
display()
```

The array that i use are

```
name=[]
age=[]
typeService=[]
price=[]
```

The error is list index out of range for price.
How do I add items to the array?  Only price array did not get the value. Did I code it wrongly?

Comment: Can you post your full error trace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\diploma in computer science\sem5\csc305\phyton\project.py", line 57, in <module>
    display()
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\diploma in computer science\sem5\csc305\phyton\project.py", line 40, in display
    print(price[i])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: 1) is price really initialized to [] *before* append? 2)are all other lists definitely at least as long as name?

Comment: Also please provide sample of inputs. With the inputs you have given there is no effect of your snippet.

Comment: Yeah so as I expected your error occurs in a section of code you haven't posted, namely `display print(price[i])`.

Comment: If you are using `name = []` your function will do _nothing_ since it won't go through for-loop.

Comment: My suspicion is that you have a `typeService[i]` that is neither 1 or 2 and thus you aren't appending an corresponding price for that name. I would need to see how you are adding your entries for anything further.

Comment: FYI, those are lists, not arrays. Python only has arrays in modules like Pandas.

Comment: It's generally poor design to have separate lists for related data like this, this isn't Fortran. Use lists of dictionaries so that you keep all the related information together as named items in each dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call `calcFee()`, so the `price` list is still empty. Call it after calling `inputUser()`

```
inputUser()
calcFee()
display()
```

Another problem is that your tests in `calcFee` won't work. `age` and `serviceType` contain strings, not numbers. You need to convert those inputs to numbers in `inputUser()`

```
def inputUser():

    name.append(raw_input("Enter name = "))
    age.append(int(raw_input("Enter age = ")))
    typeService.append(int(raw_input("Enter code of service type = ")))
    action=raw_input("Do you want to add another kitten = ")

    while action != "n":    
        name.append(raw_input("Enter name = "))
        age.append(int(raw_input("Enter age = ")))
        typeService.append(int(raw_input("Enter code of service type = ")))
        action=raw_input("Do you want to add another kitten = ")
```

And if `serviceType` isn't `1` or `2`, `calcFee()` won't append to `price`. You should add an `else` command to handle that.

```
def calcFee():
    for i in range(len(name)):
        if age[i] <= 5:
            if typeService[i] == 1:
                price.append(15)
            elif typeService[i] == 2:
                price.append(50)
            else:
                price.append(0)
        else:
            if typeService[i] == 1:
                price.append(20)
            elif typeService[i] == 2:
                price.append(60)
            else:
                price.append(0)
```

BTW, you should also use `else:` for the second part of the `if age[i] <= 5:` command, since your `elif` condition is the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of cleaning assuming python2.x as raw_input is used. Note 'input' for the age which will keep an int an int.

```
def inputUser():
  action = 'y'

  while action != "n":    
    name.append(raw_input("Enter name = "))
    age.append(input("Enter age = "))
    typeService.append(raw_input("Enter code of service type = "))
    action=raw_input("Do you want to add another kitten = ")

def calcFee():
  for i in range(len(name)):
    if age[i] <= 5:
      if typeService[i] == 1:
        price.append(15)
      elif typeService[i] == 2:
        price.append(50)
    elif age[i] > 5:
      if typeService[i] == 1:
        price.append(20)
      elif typeService[i] == 2:
        price.append(60)

def display():

  for i in range(len(name)):
    print(name[i])
    print(age[i])
    print(typeService[i])
    print(price[i])

inputUser()
calcFee()
display()
```